# jenkins chromediver protactor issues

Tags: angularjs, testing, jenkins, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am curently working in an angularjs project and I build tests with protractor. I would like to automate my tests with Jenkins. I wrote a little shell script to launch my tests and it works well from my terminal. But I have an issue when I try to launch the script from Jenkins. In the jenkins console I can see this error message :

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
[test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson2254278298273314957.sh
+ sh /home/test/Desktop/jenkins.sh
[4mRunning "connect:server" (connect) task[24m
[4mRunning "protractor:chrome" (protractor) task[24m
Waiting forever...
Started connect web server on http://localhost:3001
Using ChromeDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
```

waiting... 10 seconds

```
/home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:108
      var template = new Error(this.message);
                     ^
    UnknownError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409687 (c46e862757edc04c06b1bd88724d15a5807b84d1),platform=Linux 4.4.0-21-generic x86_64)
        at new bot.Error (/home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:108:18)
        at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (/home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/response.js:109:9)
        at /home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:160:24
        at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (/home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:1857:20)
        at [object Object].goog.defineClass.notify (/home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2448:25)
        at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (/home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:564:12)
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (/home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:553:15)
        at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (/home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/async/run.js:130:15)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
    From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
        at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:157:22)
        at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:131:30)
        at new Driver (/home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:810:36)
        at [object Object].DirectDriverProvider.getNewDriver (/home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/direct.js:68:16)
        at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (/home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:182:37)
        at /home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:263:21
        at _fulfilled (/home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
        at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
        at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
        at /home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
        at flush (/home/test/workspace/frontend/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
        at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:444:11)
        at startup (node.js:136:18)
        at node.js:966:3
    [launcher] Process exited with error code 1
    [31m>> [39m
    [33mWarning: Tests failed, protractor exited with code: 1 [4mUsed --force, continuing.[24m[39m

    [31mDone, but with warnings.[39m
    Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
    Finished: SUCCESS
```

I am completely blocked because of this problem. Do you have any clue to solve this issue?
Thank y'all!

Answer (score 0):

Based on that error, looks like you have `directConnect: true` in your config.  Jenkins cannot directly connect to the browser driver, so remove that line.

Also you are using `localhost`, don't think Jenkins can use that either.  You probably need a remote selenium server.

This is a great blog post about running Protractor against a Windows VM (it's focused on running against Internet Explorer, but provides a lot of useful information surrounding the whole process) http://elgalu.github.io/2014/run-protractor-against-internet-explorer-vm/

Comment: Are you sure `directConnect: true` doesn't work with Jenkins? it works for me and I am running jenkins locally, this issue is specific to chrome and it could be due to many reasons!

Comment: Oh, yea if you're running jenkins locally it will work.  Sorry I assumed you were running it remotely.

Answer (score 0):

> UnknownError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

It can be because of many situations.
Just make sure, jenkins slave has some display (real or virtual). Generally jenkins slave don't have the real display and hence we have to spin up some virtual display like xvfb in order to make selenium work. If selenium doesn't find any virtual display, chrome will complain with the same error : failed to start.

But there may be many other reasons as well.